# No data written to file in Matlab when using writeVideo (Ubuntu)

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

I am attempting to create a movie file from ascii data using Matlab. I am running Matlab on Ubuntu 13.10. When I run my Matlab script (see below), the frames display correctly and the .avi video file is created at the end, but there is no data in the file.

```
clc
clear all

 writerObj=VideoWriter('testVideo');
 writerObj.FrameRate = 10;
 open(writerObj);

for i=1:15000
    j=i*100;
    str=[num2str(j),'_Temp1.dat'];
    t=importdata(str);
    showaxes;
    colorbar;
    imagesc(t);
    set(gca,'ydir','normal')
    frame=getframe;
    writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
   % movieFrames(:,i) = frame;
end
close(writerObj);
```

And in Matlab I get the error:

```
Warning: No video frames were written to this file.  
The file may be invalid.  
> In VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.close at 307
In VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.delete at 256
In videomaker at 2  

Error using importdata (line 136)
Unable to open file.

Error in videomaker (line 11)
t=importdata(str);
```

Comment: try `writerObj=VideoWriter('testVideo.avi');` Also, make sure that the data you are trying to import exists. That's what the error says.

Comment: I added the .avi to the end and now at least I am getting a video file of non-zero size. However, the video still will not play. I am still getting the second set of errors in Matlab but not the first (not the "Warning" part). I have tried to play it in VLC on Ubuntu as well as on Mac OS X. In both cases the video does not play. On Mac, VLC says the video is 0.0 seconds in length.

Comment: print the `str` variable in command window and see if that data exists on the MATLAB path. You may have to give the full path.

Comment: @Parag it is printing the file names ok.

Comment: is that file on your MATLAB path? (different from being on your computer)